# single sign off

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I found out an issue at my client's site regarding single sign off.  for ease of use, i keep the client site name simple.

We developed site1.com using ektron 8.2sp2 framework and when you log into www.site1.com, you can go into "My Page" link, which takes you to www.site2.site1.com, which is a single sign-on.

This page has a log out button, when clicked, it logs off the user from www.site2.site1.com and you have a 'home' link, which takes you to www.site1.com, to log off from there too.

But, if the user just logs off from www.site2.site1.com and closes the browser, and reopens the browser to go to www.site1.com, it takes the user to the login page of www.site2.site1.com

I am trying to figure out the best way to log off the user from www.site1.com also, when the user logs off from www.site2.site1.com

I dont have access to the source files for www.site2.site1.com  So, could some one help me how i can redirect the user to logoff from www.site1.com ?

This happens only in IE 8 and Firefox 3.6 but chrome behaves wonderfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is www.site2.site1.com written in? Is it Ektron or something else?

Comment: ASP.Net 3.5 and Site1 is also written using asp.net along with ektron framework.

Comment: basically, this is what i want to achieve -  when a user tries to log into www.1site.com and he gets logged into www.2site.1site.com automatically.

But when he logs off from www2site.1site.com, i want to make the user gets logged off from www.1site.com as well.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess, the answer to this is FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); will take care of it.